# Ruby Mongoid DateTime.gte/lte query not working

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a mongoid class `User` with a `DateTime` field called `last_notification_check`

not all the `User` objects have this field, because its only added after the first time a user logs in.

I need to query for the following:

```
User.where(:last_notification_check.lte => (Time.now - 60).utc)
```

this should return a response of 1 user object, but it continuously returns `nil`

my mongoid object that it should be able to pick up:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("590ad06f78cee4ffcd612d5e"), 
    "active" : true, 
    "first_name" : "Test", 
    "last_name" : "Person", 
    "suffix" : null, 
    "email" : "test@email.com", 
    "encrypted_password" : "s7FThz4a68nBKx6aGJ19Bw==", 
    "admin" : true, 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-28T21:29:30.486+0000"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-04T06:55:42.990+0000"), 
    "title" : "Test User", 
    "last_notificaton_check" : ISODate("2017-05-28T21:29:30.485+0000")
}
```

I get the following results.. not sure what to do...

```
User.where(:last_notification_check.gte => Time.now)
# nil
User.where(:last_notification_check.lte => Time.now)
# nil
User.where(:first_name => 'Test').each do |user|
    puts user.last_name
end
# "Person"
```

Comment: how can it be `nil`? it must return empty `activerecord array`..

Comment: `User.where()` will return `mongoid criteria`, it can't be `nil`. Please check your question